# Django admin foreignkey field in form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model like

```
class Info(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Detail(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Info)
    ...
```

In admin when I add `Detail` I want all the fields of `Info` model as a form field without + sign just as normal fields.

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

its not possible as when you add some `Detail`, their `info` should already exist in `Detail` model,when parents model `info` have data, then `Detail` allow to add data with respect to parent model `Detail`.